# Can ngOnDestroy happen before ngAfterContentInit?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Suppose a component has two lifecycle hooks:

```
{
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.subscription = rx.Observable
        .interval()
        .subscribe(value => this.value = value)
    },
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Is it possible for `ngOnDestroy` to be called before `ngAfterContentInit`, and, if so, why exactly? This seems to be the case during fast enough component insertion/removal in my application. Docs are not clear about the subject.

I'm asking this question to know if `ngOnDestroy` should not assume that anything from other lifecycle callbacks is defined and bulletproof `ngOnDestroy` should perform presence checks, like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) is very clear on the order of lifecycle hooks and doesn't consider the possibility of changing the order.

Moreover, as it can be seen in [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xf7gdO5HKGtckiydH2D8?p=info), component compilation process is synchronous. If there are templates to load, they are requested prior to compilation.

The initialization should result in this log:

```
bootstrap
bootstrap tick
constructor
ngOnInit
ngAfterContentInit
ngAfterViewInit
constructor tick
```

For synchronous operations there's no opportunity for some piece of code to be 'faster' and run out of order.

`this.subscription && ...` check is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. I plan to evaluate the answer thoroughly when I have enough time to make sure it's what I was looking for.